# Determine if mobile user scanned QR code or typed URL in browser?

Tags: android, ios, html, mobile, mobile-safari

Is it possible to determine with HTML 5 or javascript (or via another method) whether a user entered a URL into a mobile browser by typing or scanned a QR code which then opened the URL in a browser?

Answer (score 2):

No, this isn't possible. Depending on whether you have control over the content of the QR-codes, you can use a deeplink that redirects to the original page (e.g. `http://www.yoursite.com/qrcode`redirecting to `http://www.yoursite.com`) and thereby "track" the usage of the QR-code.

Comment: That or [Google Analytics URL parameters](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en)  like `utm_medium=qr`